# Dialog.setCancelable(true) seems not to be working in api level 10

Tags: android, dialog

```
    final Dialog  dlg ;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        dlg= new Dialog(getActivity(),R.style.popup_theme);
    }
    else
    {
        dlg= new Dialog(getActivity());

    }
    dlg.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    dlg.setContentView(R.layout.alert_prompt_list);
    dlg.setCancelable(true);
```

I have used above code to show my dialog. It is working fine in api level above 11. But when i run the same code in device having api 10, dialog not get dismissed on clicking outside dialog.

```
dlg.setCancelable(true);
```

seems not to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your dialog creation code:

dlg.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

Comment: This behaviour was changed with Android 3.0. In earlier Android versions, touching outside the dialog window would **not** cancel the dialog. This was the default behaviour. In Android 3.0 (API 11) they changed the default behaviour.

Comment: It was really helpful.. (y)